# Ubuntu server in Google cloud won't run apps in browser

Tags: php, apache, google-app-engine, ubuntu

I've started a plain Ubuntu 15.10 instance on Google Cloud and installed a couple of apps via the command line as per their installation instructions:

http://wiki.resourcespace.org/index.php/Installing_on_Ubuntu_Linux]http://wiki.resourcespace.org/index.php/Installing_on_Ubuntu_Linux[1](http://wiki.resourcespace.org/index.php/Installing_on_Ubuntu_Linux)

webmin.com/deb.html*

*I have opened up port 10000 on the firewall for webmin.

Everything seemed to go according to plan on the command line, however in the case of both applications, when it comes to the bit where I load up the app in my browser, my browser is returning the "web page not available" message.

If I go to the base IP address of the server I get the Apache2 Ubuntu default page so I know apache is running.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why I can't see the apps in my browser?

I guess there's something I need to enable or a service I should start, but I'm honestly not sure what I should be looking for.

It's probably worth mentioning that I have another Google Cloud instance where I did the bitnami "one click install" of ResourceSpace, and on that server I separately managed to install and run webmin with no problems at all. I want to set up a clean install that directly refers back to the original software vendor for easy updates as the bitnami install is out-of-date and is proving difficult to update.

Comment: what apps have you installed, and how do they expect to make themselves available as HTTP servers to the connecting client on the given port? If you're seeing the default apache page, that means apache is active on the port, not whatever other app you expect to be there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Nick.  I fixed it... I don't think the apps I were expecting to see were properly installed.  I re-ran the installation which allowed me to see the app I was looking for in browser.

Comment: You should post the solution as a self answer, then. Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Apps weren't properly installed.
Re-ran a clean install and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening all your ports?

Comment: I haven't.  In the case of the one click install, the only ports I needed to open were for webmin.  Firewall settings are mirrored across both instances.